# Carrierwave progress information using Delayed Job with Hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, carrierwave

I'm using delayed job for some carrierwave tasks which can take some time.

At the moment I have created a simple job with a hook on success, it looks like this:

```
class VideoclipDownloadJob

  def initialize(video_id)
    @video_id = video_id
  end

  def perform
    Videoclip.grab_videoclips(@video_id)
  end

  def success(job)
    Rails.logger.info { "Videoclip downloads for video: #{@video_id} complete" }
    Video.find(@video_id).update_attribute(:videoclips_downloaded, Time.now)
  end

end
```

It works OK and I have currently implemented some AJAX polling in the browser to check when the job is complete and redirect.

However, I have two issues with this approach and would love to get some advice on this.

Firstly, if a user does not have javascript currently there is no way of redirecting them after the job is complete.

Therefore I would ideally like to include a `redirect_to` in the success hook in my job. I tried to add this directly into the success(job) method without success and also to create a method in my model to do it.

At that point it made me realise that it does not seem like a good MVC pattern.

Should I therefore rely purely on javascript or is there a better alternative?

My second question relates more to using Carrierwave.

It is working fine for the basic transferring of files, but the files can be quite large and I would really like to be able to not only show two states... downloading and complete, but also a progress (in percentage) of the actual transfer.

On the client side I can poll this information in the same way as I am for the jobs.

BUT - I cannot find in the Carrierwave documentation any mention of a way to find out the specific progress of an uploader.

Any advice on the best ways to achieve these two things would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redirect_to is a response to a browser/js request. When you have scheduled a background job and JS is disabled, you cannot redirect the user if his browser has not made any new request. And if you redirect him when his browser makes a new request, it may not be such a good idea because you may be interrupting his work.

Comment: Hi Salil, Thanks that makes sense and I kind of came to the same conclusion myself already. I think it is going to make more sense for me to change the user journey a little bit to remove the need for an explicit redirect.